Nested IF functions in Median causes error in array
I have looked at a few solutions in this forum and tried their answers, but not been able to reach a solution. I have a data set I want to determine a conditional median for.
Sample Dataset:

Desired Outcome: I want to find the median of Ages, if the BD column has an entry of FSGS or MCD.
My current formula is:
{=MEDIAN(IF(BD="MCD",IF(BD="FSGS",Age)))}

But I keep getting a #Num! error.
I have checked that the "age" field are formatted as numbers. The BD field are formatted as General (but I have gone through and retyped each to ensure there were no leading spaces etc)
I can't seem to work out the problem, can anyone can help??

Here are few ways to accomplish the desired output:


• Formula used in cell D2 --> Formula works with Excel 2021+ onwards.
=MEDIAN(FILTER(Age,MMULT(N(BD={"MCD","FSGS"}),{1;1})))


• Or, Formula used in cell D3 --> Formula works with MS365 onwards.
=MEDIAN(TOCOL(Age/((BD="MCD")+(BD="FSGS")),2))


• Or, Formula used in cell D4 --> Formula works with Excel 2021+ onwards.
=MEDIAN(FILTER(Age,1-ISNA(XMATCH(BD,{"MCD","FSGS"}))))


• Or, Using BYROW() with ETA LAMBDA --> Formula works with MS365 Office Insiders onwards.
=MEDIAN(FILTER(Age,BYROW(BD={"MCD","FSGS"},OR)))


• Or, Using IF() --> Formula works with Excel 2013+ onwards but based on ones Excel Version will need to hit CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER while exiting the edit mode.
=MEDIAN(IF((BD="MCD")+(BD="FSGS"),Age,""))



Where:
Age: =$A$2:$A$11
BD : =$B$2:$B$11


